# How can i implement multiple promises inside a loop

Tags: reactjs, promise, axios

im trying to filter images by title or description using flicker getinfo request, which returns this information.

what I'm trying to do is to send a getinfo request for each image inside currently images array, see if the title or description match the user input and if so to render this new filtered images array.

I cannot resolve how should I make a call for each image, and only after the loop is over and the filtered array is done, then call setState on that array.

```
  filterImages = (filter) =>{
    if(filter.length === 0)
      return;

    const currentImages = this.state.images;
    console.log(currentImages[0]);
    const newFilterdImages =[];
    const baseUrl = 'https://api.flickr.com/';

    for (const img of currentImages){
      axios({
      url: `services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getinfo&api_key=22c1f9009ca3609bcbaf08545f067ad&photo_id=${img.id}&&format=json&safe_search=1&nojsoncallback=1`,
      baseURL: baseUrl,
      method: 'GET'
    })
    .then(res=> res.data)
    .then(res=> {
      if( res && res.photo) {
        const imageInfo = res.photo;
        //console.log(imageInfo.title._content,imageInfo.description._content);

        if(imageInfo.title._content.includes(filter) || imageInfo.description._content.includes(filter)){
            newFilterdImages.push(img);
        }
      }
    }).then( res => console.log("first then " + newFilterdImages)) // output the newFilterdImages array on each call
    }

    this.setState({images:newFilterdImages}) // this will not work 
  }
```

how can i wait for this loop to end, and only then change the current array with new Filter Images?

Comment: you are mixing asynchronous and synchronous code. Promise are **asynchronous** so doing `newFilterdImages.push(img);` will be executed after `this.setState({images:newFilterdImages})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, a Promise represents some future result of a possibly slow operation.  Realizing the result of a Promise involves running `.then()` on it.

To make it easier to wait for a bunch of future results, the method `Promise.all()` is provided for you.  It takes a list of Promises and returns a Promise that resolves with the future values of all of the provided Promises.

Combining these points, we can run `axios` on all of the images by mapping the list of images to a list of Promises:

```
let axioses = currentImages.map((img) => {
  return axios({
      url: `services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getinfo&api_key=22c1f9009ca3609bcbaf08545f067ad&photo_id=${img.id}&&format=json&safe_search=1&nojsoncallback=1`,
      baseURL: baseUrl,
      method: 'GET'
  })
})
```

...and then running `Promise.all()` on the resulting list and treating it as a promise that resolves with a list of results from `axios()` when they're all available:

```
Promise.all(axioses).then((results) => {
      const filteredResults = results.filter((res) => {
         if (!res || !res.photo) {
            return false
         }

         const imageInfo = res.photo;

         return imageInfo.title._content.includes(filter) || imageInfo.description._content.includes(filter))
     )

     this.setState({ images: filteredResults.map(res => res.photo) })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of `Promise.all()` to wait for all the images to resolve before filtering them and assigning to state

```
filterImages = (filter) =>{
    if(filter.length === 0)
      return;

    const currentImages = this.state.images;
    console.log(currentImages[0]);
    const newFilterdImages =[];
    const baseUrl = 'https://api.flickr.com/';
    const promises = [];
    for (const img of currentImages){
      promises.push(axios({
      url: `services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getinfo&api_key=22c1f9009ca3609bcbaf08545f067ad&photo_id=${img.id}&&format=json&safe_search=1&nojsoncallback=1`,
      baseURL: baseUrl,
      method: 'GET'
    })
    .then(res=> res.data)
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then((data) => {
        data.forEach((item, index) => {
             if( item && item.photo) {
                 const imageInfo = res.photo;
                 if(imageInfo.title._content.includes(filter) || imageInfo.description._content.includes(filter)){
                       newFilterdImages.push(currentImages[index]);
                 }
             }
        });
        this.setState({images:newFilterdImages})
    })
  }
```

Comment: `newFilterdImages.push(img);` -> `img is not defined`

Comment: you need to get the index`data.forEach((item, index) {...` then push the corresponding image in the array `newFilterdImages.push(currentImages[index]);`

Comment: @OlivierBoissé Thanks for the comment. I updated my answer, didn't pay attention to that